# STB Library Quicksort Implementation

Tags: c, sorting

I am reading the source code for Sean Barrett's "stb.h" library, and I have a question about the implementation of Quick Sort.

https://pastebin.com/gpfXTuL8

So, I am particularly confused about the following excerpt:

```
/* recurse on smaller side, iterate on larger */                        \
  if (j < (n-i)) {                                                        \
     STB_(FUNCNAME,_quicksort)(p,j);                                       \
     p = p+i;                                                             \
     n = n-i;                                                             \
  } else {                                                                \
     STB_(FUNCNAME,_quicksort)(p+i, n-i);                                  \
     n = j;                                                               \
  }
```

i don't get why the library chooses to recurse on the smaller side and iterate on the larger one; in the end aren't they both just going to execute the function from the beginning with updated p and n? i don't speak English too well, so if you need further clarification, I would be glad to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating on the larger part and only using recursion for the smaller part reduces used stack space to O(log(n)), otherwise worst case stack space is O(n). The worst case time complexity remains at O(n^2). Time complexity can be reduced by checking for excessive number of partition splits and switching to heap sort if the splits become excessive, such as intro sort.

Comment: cool. do you have any resources as to how i can calculate the O(log(n)) for worst case stack space? it makes sense to me that we would want to reduce the stack overhead due to recursions, but how do you know that if we recurse on the smaller half it requires O(log(n)) stack space? Thanks!

my theory is that worst case the smaller half is n/2 elements, so since it is halved every time O(log(n)). I'm not a Computer Scientist, so my understanding of Order notation is a little bit bad, but is this true?

Comment: Assume that the smaller part is 1/2 of the current sub-array. Then it will take log2(n) levels of recursion where the smaller part only contains a single element. Think of this as raising 1/2 to the power of the level of recursion, then (1/2)^(⌈log2(n)⌉)  ~= 1/n, and 1/n * n = 1.

Comment: thanks i appreciate your assistance. that helped me a lot.